# Error while running the web application in eclipseIndigo

Tags: java

when i am running a servlet web application in eclipse indigo  the tomcat apache server is not start and it will print the following error in the console.

```
    Nov 5, 2012 10:51:11 AM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.7.0\bin;.;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.7.0/bin/client;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.7.0/bin;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.7.0/lib/i386;C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\bin;;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\bin;C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Nero\Lib\;D:\eclipseIndigo;
Nov 5, 2012 10:51:11 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:ServletDemo' did not find a matching property.
Nov 5, 2012 10:51:11 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:DemoPro' did not find a matching property.
Nov 5, 2012 10:51:12 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8085"]
Nov 5, 2012 10:51:12 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Nov 5, 2012 10:51:12 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 2253 ms
Nov 5, 2012 10:51:12 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Nov 5, 2012 10:51:12 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.21
Nov 5, 2012 10:51:13 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
SEVERE: Catalina.start: 
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardServer[8005]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:152)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:621)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:322)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:450)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardService[Catalina]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:152)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:727)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:148)
    ... 7 more
```

Comment: can you start it directly. i mean without deploying your web application?

Comment: After writing the program i going to the project and run-run in server option to the web application

Comment: try to start tomcat without your application. if that's possible. Pls post your codes including web.xml

Comment: Check whether [this](http://tomcat.10.n6.nabble.com/Error-starting-Tomcat-td2062112.html) helps

Comment: After staring the tomcat without my application it gives  the following error                                                        SEVERE: Catalina.start: 
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardServer[8005]]
 at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:152)
 at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:621)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Source)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at

Answer (score 1):

You cut/pasted a lot of the error message ... but I think you skipped the part that matters :)

Look at this link:

- [tomcat and netbeans deployment errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8152999/tomcat-and-netbeans-deployment-errors)

1) They're using NetBeans (you're using Eclipse - but it probably doesn't matter)

2) They got exactly the same traceback as you showed above:

```
...
16 Νοε 2011 4:02:16 μμ org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase addChildInternal
SEVERE: ContainerBase.addChild: start: 
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:152)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:812)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:787)
    ....
```

3) But they also showed the important part of the traceback:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.servlet.ServletContext.getSessionCookieConfig()Ljavax/servlet/SessionCookieConfig;
    at org.apache.catalina.deploy.WebXml.configureContext(WebXml.java:1308)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1343)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:896)
```

4) The root cause in this example was that the code used `getSessionCookieConfig()`, which was introduced in Java 6, but they inadvertantly deployed an old, pre-Java6 version of servlet.jar.  The solution was to double-check all of their deployments, making sure the correct .jar's were deployed.

'Hope that helps ..